# Opengl context in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, opengl-es-2.0

My Android project uses an opengl lib written in c++, I'm using an Android SurfaceView subclass, now I would like to recreate my app starting with a flutter project. Some of you know how can I achieve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may find [this article helpful](https://medium.com/@germansaprykin/opengl-with-texture-widget-f919743d25d9) which shows how to use Flutters  TextureRegistry to obtain SurfaceTextures that you can then render into.

But given you say you are using a SurfaceView at the moment, you'll need to find some way to wire up your c++ lib differently for Flutter.

In my use case I needed to do what you are trying to do, use a c++ library rather than Java GLES code as in the article I linked.
So what I did was use EGL call in Java side to create an EGLSurface

```
mEGL.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEGLDisplay, mEGLConfig, texture, null)
```

which I could then make use of in C++ code that ran on the same thread, so I had access to the EGLSurface to render it into.

Comment: Hi, nice example I am doing a 3D app with flutter using OpenglES but I get memory leaks, can you explain how I can do it with C++. Do you have any github repository so I will find an example. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry @GeorgeC. I don't have any publicly available sample code for this.

Comment: Don't warry @Maks I understand. Have a nice day :)

Comment: hi @GeorgeC. did you able to find solution?

Comment: hi @KalanaPerera my work so far you can find it in pub.dev as "flgl" you can analyze the code, but I have stop the development. Maybe I will focus again in the future. Good luck